# Windows 8 GUI, and WPF/SilverLight/WinRT/Metro/BUILD relations

Tags: wpf, windows-8, microsoft-metro

**FIXED**:

I'm not working with any of technologies specified above, and I was not able to find current information about the the relation between the technologies in the title, so I would be glad if anyone can explain me roughly all this subject..

Based on facts and official Microsoft information, is WPF still relevant? I remember a lot of titles about WPF being dead, about a year ago. What made people say that? Has anything changed during the last year?

Beside, what knowledge is needed for metro/WinRT/build? Is knowing WPF is helpful for any of these? How much?

I have found similar questions, but they are from about a year ago, and I think some stuff have been changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That could be a long conversation... :)  I'll keep it short as possible...

WPF -> Preferred XAML-based technology for building desktop applications on Windows.

WinRT apps -> next generation platform for building applications that can be delivered through the Windows Store.  Your choice of HTML/js stack, XAML/C#/VB, or XAML/C++.  The choice of stack is based on your skill set and application needs.
--- HTML/js -> leverage web dev skills and exisiting assets to create WinRT apps
--- XAML/C#/VB -> leverage your .NET and/or XAML skills and assets to create WinRT apps
--- XAML/C++ -> same as above but for C++ and also provides access to things like DirectX

In general, the stacks are relatively equal (outside of DirectX that is C++ only), though some make some things easier than others.  It is more a skill/asset choice than anything.  Again, this is a broad brush and depending on what your requirements you may find one stack better than another.

WinRT and the desktop both continue on the Intel platform.  The ARM platform has WinRT but you cannot deploy desktop apps.

Comment: Ah, but would you speculate on whether WPF will see any further development .... ?

Comment: @Erno - When the question asks about "2012 and beyond" and Microsoft has given no comfort about future directions, it clearly invites speculation. You might consider the question inappropriate.... but it is a serious issue for developers making long-term technology choices.

Comment: @Govert - I agree that it is an issue but it should be taken to Microsoft or Programmers StackExchange. Not here.

Comment: @Jeff-Brand - so, wpf knowledge is relevant for WinRT? and what made people say wpf is dead?

Answer (score 1):

WPF was enhanced in .NET 4.5, the .NET Framework version that comes with Win8.  So not dead in Windows 8, enhanced.... Made better faster, stronger than it was before.  Writing apps that don't target WinRT, aka are desktop, you've still got tons of options, as you've noted.

Just as an FYI, some pretty cool enhancements to WPF in 4.5.  Stuff like Ribbon Control, performance enhancements, binding enhancements and a variety of other goodies.  See the MSDN doc for a full list at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588(v=VS.110).aspx .